# Cannot assign to a services local variable using observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, angular2-observables

## Summary

I'm trying to cache HTTP results into a local variable by assigning the `JobService` `jobs:Job[]` variable to the result of the request. I then wish to filter the results invoking the `setSearch()` function from another component that injects the `JobService`.

When the `UserService` retrieves the user, the `JobService` subscribes to the event and gets the jobs. This means that if the user state changes so does the jobs array. This then invokes `setJobs()` to set the local `jobs` variable

Later when a user types in the search box, `setSearch()` is called and `this.jobs` is an empty array even though it was set in `setJobs()`

The `jobsPublisher` then publishes this new set of jobs to the subscribers.

**Note**: `HttpCacheService` is very similar to `Http` but it just maps the response to the object desired, whilst handling and logging errors.

#### JobService

```
@Injectable()
export class JobService {
    jobsPublisher: BehaviorSubject<Job[]>
    private jobs: Job[] = []

    constructor(
        private http: HttpCacheService<Job[]>,
        private userService: UserService,
        private searchService: SearchService
    ) {
        this.jobsPublisher = new BehaviorSubject<Job[]>(this.jobs)

        this.userService.userPublisher.subscribe((user: User) => {
            this.getJobs()
        })
    }

    private getJobs(): void {
        let req = this.http.GET("/d/jobs").subscribe(jobs => {
            this.setJobs(jobs) // jobs = Array(100)
            this.jobsPublisher.next(jobs)
            req.unsubscribe()
        })
    }

    private setJobs(jobs) {
        console.log("Setting jobs!")
        this.jobs = jobs // this.job = jobs = Array(100)
    }

    setSearch(query: string) { // this.jobs = []
        let newJobs = this.filterJobs(query, this.jobs)
        console.log(`Job Length Filter [${this.jobs.length}] -> [${newJobs.length}]`)
        this.jobsPublisher.next(newJobs)
    }

    private filterJobs(query: string, jobs: Job[]): Job[] {
         // Filter jbos
    }
}
```

#### JobListComponent

```
export class JobsListComponent implements OnInit {
  public jobrows: Array<Array<Job>> = []

  constructor(private jobService: JobService, private searchService: SearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jobService.jobsPublisher.subscribe((jobs: Job[]) => {
      this.genRows(jobs)
    })
  }

  private genRows(jobs: Array<Job>): void {
    this.jobrows = []
    while (jobs.length > 0) 
      this.jobrows.push(jobs.splice(0, 3))
  }

  search(event: any): void {
    this.jobService.setSearch(event.target.value || "")
  }
}
```

[Not working](https://github.com/lengk/bug-observable)

[Working as expected](https://embed.plnkr.co/vcDfB0tmA7ByTCR8Yi2r)

Comment: what is the question, are you getting errors ? what are you expecting and what is happening. Ideally you should not be using `subscribe` in services

Comment: @Skeptor when `setSearch()` is called, this.jobs is an empty array.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the services from the component .

Comment: @Skeptor I added the component

Comment: What is the actual content of filterJobs ? Because as it stands now in the code you have given it's just a comment. Is it actually a comment in your code ? If not then please put the adequate code so we don't have to assume you did things correctly.

Comment: @Ced It takes a list of jobs and returns a smaller list of jobs. The problem is the list it is getting is always empty. I've commented the value of the `this.jobs` at various stages in the program

Comment: @Harry ok things are clearer in my mind now

Comment: @Harry You have multiple ngModule right ? Put some log in the constructor of the service, I wouldn't be surprised you have more than one that is being created.

Comment: @Ced No just the required AppModule

Comment: @Ced I tried that and it only printed once

Comment: will provide a answer

Comment: @Harry It would be nice if you put jobs as private. That'd give us the proof that you are not changing jobs somewhere else in your code. Just so I understand correctly, you are saying that the state of the user doesn't change but the job array does ?

Comment: @Ced Sure thing, its not being used anywhere else. The `UserService` get the user information from localStorage, it then publishes this to the subscribers i.e. `JobsService`. Once this has happened, the `JobService` queries the server for jobs, its cookies determining the role it is in.

Comment: @Ced Have you managed to recreate the problem?

Comment: @Harry I gave some suggestions in a comment. If you want a real answer I'd suggest reproducing the error in a plunkr.

Comment: @Ced Thanks, Plunkr version doesn't ahve the problem so it must be something else created a repo with the project in it to look at

https://github.com/lengk/bug-observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private genRows(jobs: Array<Job>): void {
    jobs = jobs || []
    this.jobrows = []
    while (jobs.length > 0) 
      this.jobrows.push(jobs.splice(0, 3))
  }
```

is the culprite you are changing the array.

transform it to:

```
          this.jobrows.push(jobs.slice(0, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions @Ced. Yes it's a strange one not sure what is going on. I'm making a plunker for you will be very annoyed if it works in there.

Comment: Of course it works https://embed.plnkr.co/vcDfB0tmA7ByTCR8Yi2r/

Not sure why its not working in my project though

Comment: @Cred So I've made a repo that has the server etc in it: https://github.com/lengk/bug-observable

Comment: I also tried to see if the getter and setter implmentation you suggested made any difference but it didn't :(

Comment: @Harry I didn't mean it would make a difference, I meant it would help you resolve the issue. If you'd like more help I'd suggest comming on the angular gitter. https://gitter.im/angular/angular

Comment: Ah ok sorry yes I'll post in there